# Exporting cycles material as .MTL file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

My use case is to obtain the material coefficients for simple material classes (metals, plastics, wood, fabric, glass etc). As an example, I have created a simple metal gold in Blender 2.79 using the following steps:

1. Choose the cycles renderer
2. Add Monkey mesh
3. Material -> Glossy BSDF
4. Pick color of gold (`#FFD700`)
5. Render (Shift + Z)

Now, I want to see what the .MTL coefficients of this material are. To that end, I exported the .OBJ file (which generated its associated .MTL file). But the values in my .MTL file are default values. Moreover, when I re-import the .OBJ into blender, it doesnt show my metal.

My question is: Is there any way I can view the .MTL coefficients of this simple material?

**What has been tried:** There is one answer [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-export-materials-and-textures-from-cycles-render/630681), but I was not able to "pack" anything. In fact I do not know how to pack material properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures). In your case - .mtl files don't hold material definitions, they **can** hold texture definitions, which means that you need to bake textures and recreate the materials in whatever you want to import the .obj file into.

Comment: I'd suggest have a look into the source `/blender/2.79/addons/io_scene_obj/export_obj.py`. According to wikipedia (file specs), there is: Ka (ambient), Kd (diffuse), Ks (specular) and Ke (environment).

Comment: Thank you @metaphor_set. It is likely that I'm using terminologies wrong. I'm already applying textures from images.  So I simply need the Ka, Kd, Ks etc for common material classes. I wasnt able to locate these online, but if it exists, it will obviate any need to save materials.